# python sys.exit :an integer is required (got type str)?

Tags: python

New to python.
I want to stop my code in main for debugging purpose. I use logging module to print the variable value I would like to inspect.

However, it raises error. Not sure how to solve it.
I also wonder using sys.exit instead of set up debugging point is the right way to run only small portion of the code. My main is long and I don't want to run the whole thing every time.

```
import linecache
import logging
import sys

import pandas as pd


def print_exception():
    exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    f = tb.tb_frame
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
    print('EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, -1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1],
                           'B': [12, 12, 14, 15, 14, 16, 200]})

        sys.exit('error')



    except:
        print_exception()

EXCEPTION IN (<ipython-input-9-f42a2adee11e>, LINE 49 "sys.exit('error')"): an integer is required (got type str)
```

Updates: I've updated the full code. I'm on python3 with Pycharm.

Comment: I don't think this is as trivial as others are making it out to be. OP's usage of sys.exit is consistent with the docs.

Comment: @wim this code works fine on Python 2.7.8 and is consistent with the sys.exit() documentation. I suspect there is a context issue somewhere that isn't in this code (since obviously it is not 49 lines long).

Comment: @Karin I agree, I think people are taking the error at face value, but something else is going on as this usage worked fine for me on both linux and windows in a quick test and is documentation consistent. Haven't tried Python 3 yet

Comment: OP, could you please provide the rest of the code?

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right.  I was getting mixed up with `os._exit`, my bad.

Comment: Yes, context code and also version info for Python if you please, because now I'm curious

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce this error for ourselves.

Comment: does this only occur in python 3? Because in python 2.7 one does not need an integer

Comment: @Karin Indeed, this is the error that `os._exit` will make when you pass it a string - so as a guess it would seem `sys.exit` is passing that to `os._exit` somehow....IPython maybe?

Comment: Are you running this code directly in the terminal, or are you running it in some IDE or editor? Also, _please_ tell us what Python version you're using.

Comment: A non-integer arg to `sys.exit` is acceptable in Python 3 too. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: I'd also be curious what the output of `print(sys.exit)` is

Comment: @Lost Please see the updates

Comment: @Karin Please see the updates

Comment: In Python3 this still works as expected and ends with your custom print_exception code sending: EXCEPTION IN (test.py, LINE 24 "sys.exit('error')"): error -- Maybe iPython is not handling the exception properly. Do you have pure Python3 available to you? sys.exit() raises an exception which is why your print exception is running. By if iPython doesn't like sys.exit('exit') it may be raising its own error first/exclusively

Comment: @Lost do you mean sys.exit() raises an exception instead of stopping the script from running?

Comment: @Lisa sys.exit() raises the SystemExit exception which inherits from BaseException [Exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) so it's possible to catch and handle a sys.exit() and prevent it actually exiting the program if desired. To illustrate: `try:` `sys.exit()` `except:` `print("You tried to escape and failed")`

Comment: But in pure Python3, I ran your exact code and it successfully ended the program with the custom error message (as handled by your error handling print_exception() code). So whatever is happening to give you that integer error is maybe a symptom of some sort of iPython error handling -- it may be mistaking the sys.exit() combined with your custom error handling as something other than what it is. I don't have iPython setup to test with though, so that would be a weekend project for me setting up a new environment to test. If you had Python3 available to you, might see if error replicates there

Comment: Also regarding pyCharm, if you are trying to run this IN PyCharm it may have its own error handling to prevent you exiting pyCharm which may cause this error. If you are testing in PyCharm, try running your file directly from your system console

Comment: @Lost Thank you for great explanation. You inspired me to play with the Pycharm abit. In Pycharm, if i use shit+control+E to load the code to Python Console, the exception is raised. However, if I click "run" button to run the code, No errors.  Not sure whats going on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comment discussion, I suspect your issue is that PyCharm is trying to handle the sys.exit() internally and it doesn't like the fact you are using a custom error message. There are similar issues in other IDEs like Python logging not working properly in Spyder (May or may not have been resolved by now).

Your usage itself seems valid and is consistent with the documentation for Python3 and I had no trouble running your code on my system and it performed as expected.

I suggest you try running the code with Python directly and not using PyCharm and see if that clears up the issue. If Python3 is your default python installation, you should only have to open a BASH Terminal or Command Prompt in the file's directory and type:

```
python file-name.py
```

To run the program in the terminal. I suspect this will work fine and what you've really done here is not debugged your program but found a bug (or feature) in pycharm.

Answer (score -8):

You do need an integer - a traditional Unix return code (0 for no error, and something bigger than 0 for something bad happening).

In terms of debugging, you should try the [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_(Python)) IDE, or [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Comment: This is untrue. At least in python 2.7 this is valid code. There must be a different problem

Comment: It's also untrue in Python 3. See the docs link in my comment on the question.