# Returning JSON to AJAX after using sys.exit()

Tags: python, json, ajax, cgi

I'm working with a local web application which executes, via AJAX, a Python script on the web-server.

I tried to deploy the application on a remote server and since have been facing an AJAX `statusText: "parsererror"`.

I assume this is because it isn't receiving proper JSON as expected when the script fails. **How could I make sure the script interruption returns JSON to the browser, so that I can understand the nature of the error?**

---

The AJAX call is the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "cgi-bin/myscript.py",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
        data: JSON.stringify(run_details), 
        dataType: "JSON"
    })
    .done(function(data) { 
            console.log(data)
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      console.log('Error in myscript (cf. Ajax error below).');
      console.log('error',xhr);
    });
```

In working conditions, I return data to the client using the following approach, which works well on the local server:

```
success_message = "Some text"
result = {'message': success_message};   

#Send JSON result back to Ajax
print("This line allows the following to be received by browser \n")
json.dump(result, sys.stdout)
```

In case an error in the script occurs, I call this function to interrupt the script:

```
def interruptScript(a_cursor, a_conn, error_message):
    # Close communication with the database
    a_cursor.close()
    a_conn.close()   
    #Add error message to object
    result = {'message': error_message};   

    #Send JSON result back to Ajax
    print("This lines allows the following to be received by browser \n")
    json.dump(result, sys.stdout)                      
    sys.exit(1)
```

Ideally, I'd like the error_message to be accessible in AJAX's "responseText" (which is now empty "").

So far, I tried including a string (i.e. `sys.exit(error_message)`) and a JSON string (i.e. `sys.exit(json.dumps(result))`) in `sys.exit()`, but debugging in PyDev I learned that `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`, and that this might be a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877777/python-sys-exit-an-integer-is-required-got-type-str). For this reason, I finally added the integer `1`, with hope that the `json.dump` content would be passed via AJAX before the `sys.exit`.

---

UPDATE:
I found what was causing the error (a missing python package on the remote server's python install). However I'll keep the question open, because in principle I'm still interested to know how to ensure that the error message from Python (whether from my custom interruptScript() function, or directly from Python informing a package is not installed) gets properly pushed to the browser. I'm using cgitb.enable(), so the question is mostly, **how to push the error message if AJAX is expecting JSON?**